# How is the due date for landing gear replacement determined?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, landing-gear, md-80

I want to know how calculate the due date of Boeing MD-83 Landing gear replacement (it is every 10 year or 20000 FC).

Is it calculated from the installed date or shop visit date?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. This sounds like a question that should be answered by the OEM or qualified mechanic.

Comment: @Notts90 That would indeed be a good way to get an answer, but it still seems to me that the question could be answered by someone here. It's specific and factual, so why not?

Comment: @Pondlife It could but I doubt such information is readily available on the internet to provide a credible reference (happy to be proven wrong). Hence the best place to get an official answer would be the OEM.

Comment: @Notts90 Information not readily available through Google is exactly one of the reasons why this site exists, to answer difficult questions like this. Some of us have OEM books or knowledge.

Comment: @JonathanWalters Yes but for a safety aspect I think that isn't a good enough source. I think you should only take that information from an OEM source (in person, book or website). I'm not saying we can't answer it here, just the best answer would be via OEM in this case.

Comment: @Notts90 True, if such questions are coming from professionals, or the "qualified mechanic" as you say, this may not be the best forum. However, there is a place for [such questions](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24566/12720) even if asked by professionals, but especially if asked by the curious non-professional.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, all lifed components are tracked from installed date. That is from personal experience, but I can certainly have a look through the regs to find an official source, if you require.

Comment: Aren't some components checked or repaired after a given number of cycles rather than after a number of days?

Comment: Oh, absolutely. That is actually what FC refers to (flight cycles) vs FH (flight hours). Really depends on the component. Obviously it wouldn't make much sense to limit landing gear based on hours flown, but rather on flight cycles. That having been said, components are often limited in both time and usage. Something along the lines of overhaul at x months or y flight cycles/hours, and using whichever is more limiting, is pretty common. The question is simply asking for when the cycles/hours or days are tracked from though. That would be install date

Comment: Ah I understand now, I missed the meaning of the question, as you may have guessed already.